# PHP cURL cookie problems

Tags: php, post, cookies, curl

I have the strangest problem:

if i try to post a cookie with curl i get a http_code 500,
when i leave the cookie out it works normally?!

i added the cookie like this:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'someCookie=' . $_COOKIE['someCookie'] . '; path=/');
```

Any ideas? Just hints, bounce ideas..anything

curl_info:

```
Array (
     [url] => valid url
     [content_type] => text/html; charset=utf-8
     [http_code] => 500
     [header_size] => 279
     [request_size] => 270
     [filetime] => -1
     [ssl_verify_result] => 0
     [redirect_count] => 0
     [total_time] => 0.345595
     [namelookup_time] => 2.3E-5
     [connect_time] => 0.000122
     [pretransfer_time] => 0.000126
     [size_upload] => 1026
     [size_download] => 52106
     [speed_download] => 150771
     [speed_upload] => 2968
     [download_content_length] => -1
     [upload_content_length] => 1026
     [starttransfer_time] => 0.000814
     [redirect_time] => 0
     [certinfo] => Array ( )
     [redirect_url] =>
)
```

Note: no errors happen and i see everything in access log (http_code 500 though)

I can successfully execute the command from the command line so are there any ideas as to what may be preventing php from executing it?

Comment: Do you have access to that server's logs? The error log will contain more details about the 500.

Comment: i thought the  "/" should be a file name like "/cookie.txt" which you have permission to write to

Comment: Marc B: yeah i do...which one? access log and error log are clean, omoabobade: thats cookie-jar

Comment: whichever server you're sending this cookie to that's giving you the 500 error. y

Comment: yeah but which specific log? i have access to them all

Comment: Update: i tried a console curl and it works just fine...so its probably a php/curl bug...any ideas, workarounds, etc now? i tried to modify the header and it did not work

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#87112 might be relavent. You should try using a variable to set cookie string instead of using concatenation in function parameter. I know it sounds illogical but i'd give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the most idiotic problem i had ever seen was happening because of the path

i dont know why or how...but when i removed it, it worked just fine

edit:
so after about 4 hours of research an do-try-redo testing i figured it out: path in combination with an internal server error...

of course the error was not logged in any log, anyway tnx 4 the help

Comment: Because cookie headers in HTTP *requests* do not contain paths. Paths are used when *setting* cookies (in HTTP *responses*); if a cookie's path does not match the request URI, it is simply not sent. Not having to send a list of cookies and paths for the server to parse is the reason the path attribute exists in the spec.

Comment: i know only the key,value pair is sent, but the funny thing is that i shoud then get a custom 403 code not a 500...

now i have a new problem...again i get a http 500 code but this time with the path left out?